# how to prevent mysql user from showing all databases

Tags: mysql

0.82sp1 running and i've noticed that every user can see all databases by invoking `show databases;` command. Even if i revoke all privileges for given user. Is there some setting that allows showing databases by default? How can i stop this.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-databases.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: Stolen from ajreal comment

[From dev.mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-databases.html):

> If the server was started with the --skip-show-database option, you
>   cannot use this statement (SHOW DATABASES) at all unless you have the SHOW DATABASES
>   privilege.