# How to prevent users from having read only access to all databases' tables?

Tags: mysql

I have mysql 5.0.82sp1 running and i've noticed that all users can invoke select command on all databases' tables. They don't have privileges to do so, so there's nothing i can revoke. Is there some mysql setting granting this read-only access by default?

this seems to always give result

`select * from some_database_name.some_table_name`

and it shows whatever is in it.

it works even if i revoke all privileges by issuing command

`revoke all privileges, grant option  from 'username'@'localhost';`

and i check it by issuing command

`show grants;`

it shows

`GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '...'`

which means it doesn't have privileges to select

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to prevent mysql user from showing all databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307782/how-to-prevent-mysql-user-from-showing-all-databases), Why you keep asking the same question?

Comment: it not really same question after --skip-show-database when i'm logged in as user i cannot execute show databases any longer, which is good, however if i know database and table name i still can read from it

Comment: you do need to understand what are the type of privileges in mysql, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html

Comment: yes please enlighten me. for instance i revoked all privileges for one of mysql user and still select * from database.table worked

Comment: `select=read privileges` and if you want to disallow an user from `select`, you should just dropped the user

Comment: try this ? `select host, Select_priv from mysql.user;`

Comment: it's the matter of user not being able to read from other user's table's not to drop it all together, and it's Select_priv is N

Comment: I surrender. You can try to ask the question to http://serverfault.com, they have lots of mysql expert users

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that nobody can enter any MySQL commands in your database query fields.. If the users don't have access, they cannot use it either. 
If you are the only one that should use the database, just create 1 account for yourself and make sure that no anonymous access is allowed.

But if you want users to log in or something like that, you should make sure that this is handled in an application of (if users can access the database directly) They should not be able to execute any queries..

Hope this helps, if not, please say so and i might clarify.